# When will the file descriptor be allocated to a file?

Tags: file, operating-system

I have searched it through some technology blogs, Google, Wikipedia and even Youtube Video Tutorial, but I am still confused because it seems contrary to what my teacher asked me to do.

1.When will the file descriptors be allocated to a file, after the file is open or created?

2.If the file descriptors are allocated after the file is open, can I use the function like `open(int fileDescriptors, int mode)` to open the file? How? (Cause this is what my teacher asked me to do). If I cannot, maybe the teacher is wrong.

I hope my questions are clear.

Comment: _"I hoped my questions are clear."_ Unfortunately not.

Comment: You are probably confusing something. The variable for the file descriptor is allocated at declaration `int fd = -1;` , The associated file resource is allocated with the `open()` call like `fd = open("MyFile.txt");`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, "file descriptors" as you are talking about them are a eunuchs concept that does not exist in all operating systems.

The exact operating differs among variants. At the risk over overgeneralization, each process has a number of file descriptors (512 and 1024 are common values). Generally most of these descriptors sit unused. The descriptor has to be mapped to a file in order to be used.

> 1.When will the file descriptors be allocated to a file, after the file is open or created?

Creating a file opens the file. Descriptors are mapped when a file is opened.

> 2.If the file descriptors are allocated after the file is open, can I use the function like open(int fileDescriptors, int mode) to open the file?

The file descriptors exist before the file is opened. Opening maps the file to a descriptor.